# How could I split image into 1 pixel sgements?

Tags: images, image-format, image-quality

Suppose that we have 400x400 bitmap pixel RGB dimensions, I need to split it into 160000 segments so each segment has its own resolution so when we zoom in, the whole image resolution will not be affected by zooming in.In other words make each pixel as a separated image file, arrange all images one beside each other to make the whole image, like a puzzle, so the whole resulted image will not be affected by  zooming in .

Comment: This sounds more like a coding issue than a design issue...?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. What do you mean 'not affected by zooming in'?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same question as the one that was closed as off topic previously.

As asked, this is a programming topic, not a GD topic, and I think the idea as expressed is a very naive implementation.

To point you in the right direction, look at ( http://www.zoomify.com/ )